# How to Programmatically Scroll a ScrollView to Bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I've a problem I can't solve: inside a ScrollView I only have a
LinearLayout. By a user action I'm programmatically adding 2 TextView
on this LinearLayout, but by the default the scroll keeps on the top.
Since I controll the user action, I should be easy to scroll to the
bottom with something like:

```
ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getBottom());
```

But actually not. Because immediately after adding this two new
elements getBottom() still returns the previous two. I tried to
refresh the state invoking `refreshDrawableState()`, but I doesn't work.

Do you have any idea how could I get the actual bottom of a ScrollView
after adding some elements?

Comment: Actually ScrollView may change or not change it's height(it is a container for LinearLayout). Try to use getBottom() of ScrollView's first(and single) child LinearLayout.

Comment: Both containers (ScrollView and LinearLayout) look that they have the same issue: the bottom position doesn't reflect the last added items :-/

Comment: Post the code, where you're adding new elements. It is hard to say without your code. I think, it may be weights issue or something.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This doesn't actually answer your question.
But it's an alternative which pretty much does the same thing.

Instead of Scrolling to the bottom of the screen, change the focus to a view which is located at the bottom of the screen.

That is, Replace:

```
scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getBottom());
```

with:

```
Footer.requestFocus();
```

Make sure you specify that the view, say 'Footer' is focusable.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: This focusable property is very nice to be used in this scenario... when having complex layout.. thanks

Comment: I am finding it difficult to get the view at the bottom of the screen.   I have a ListView that contains TextViews.  I've attempted listView.getItemAtPosition(elementCount -1)  to get that text view,  but instead it returns a String instead of a view.   I suspect that I will need to make a custom arrayAdapter in this case.

Comment: when there's a button at the bottom then ripple effect would be shown in the button which makes it weired!

Comment: It works perfectly if you are doing showCaseView

Comment: If you call `footer.requestFocus()` several times, don't forget to remove focus! `footer.clearFocus()` or `another_edit_text.requestFocus()` and then `footer.requestFocus()`.

Answer (score 149):

You need to use the message queue or else it won't work.  Try this:

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: this also works for NestedScrollView, i tried. Thanks

Comment: this is the recommended for full scroll, scrollTo() methods does not scroll to full top.

Answer (score 21):

this will be ok

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override

    public void run() {

        scroll.scrollTo(0, scroll.getBottom());

    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)`?

Comment: `scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)` was the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Since, I am also using hide keyboard, below code with a delay of 200 milli second worked better for me.
Note: I just replaced post() with postDelayed() from above examples:

```
    final ScrollView scrollView_main = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView_main);
    scrollView_main.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView_main.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    }, 200);
```

Comment: this is copied from another answer

Comment: I had already added note.
Note: I just replaced post() with postDelayed() from above examples
The issue with me is, I am also using hide keyboard. hence post() did not help me.

     "200 milliseconds" delay did the magic for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply this also

```
 mScrollviewHomepage.setScrollY(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Answer (score -1):

I Hope it Work

Try this:

nsscroll.post(new Runnable() {
@Override

```
                    public void run() {

                        nsscroll.scrollTo(0, nsscroll.getBottom());

                    }
                });
```