# Android: scroll down after animation of LinearLayout.addview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I want to make a list of items which are in a Scrollview.
So I put a LinearLayout inside a Scrollview.
There is already one item inside the linearLayout: a view to add items.
I want that item to stay at the bottom of my list at all times. (which a accomplished)

But when I add an item by executing the code below, my item to add views goes out of the screen.

```
linearLayout.addView(theview, linearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
```

The views get inserted animated:

```
screen.android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

So my Question is how I scroll my scrollView down during the animation, so my item stays on the screen.

These are some screenshots. 
[image: my screenshots]

Thanx

Comment: try something like: myScrollView.scrollTo(0, myView.getY()+50);

Comment: Yes, but when do i call that.. I cant scroll down immediately after i did linearLayout.addview because it is animated

Answer (score 1):

You should call scrollTo or fullScroll inside post method, after addView.

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

ref: [How to Programmatically Scroll a ScrollView to Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015313/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scrollview-to-bottom)

Answer (score 0):

Realization for a smooth scroll for `ScrollView` after layout animation ends.

First add `LayoutTransition` type in the code, not in xml

```
final LayoutTransition layoutTransition = mainLinearLayoutContainer.getLayoutTransition();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
    layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
}
layoutTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0);
```

Then create `LayoutTransition.TransitionListener` item to have ability to multiple adding/removing it.
Also you need to remove **transitionListener** in the end of translation because **endTransition()** callback is called multiple times and it brokes smoothScroll.

```
final LayoutTransition.TransitionListener transitionListener = new LayoutTransition.TransitionListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void startTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) {}

    @Override
    public void endTransition(LayoutTransition transition, ViewGroup container, View view, int transitionType) 
    {
        // Remove TransitionListener because endTransition is called multiple times and it brokes smoothScroll
        layoutTransition.removeTransitionListener(this);
        scrollContainer.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollContainer.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollContainer.getBottom());
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Finnaly add animation start point.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if (licenseLabel.getVisibility() == View.GONE) 
        {
            layoutTransition.addTransitionListener(transitionListener);
            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } 
        else {
            licenseLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
});
```