# Layout with scrollview: how to reach the bottom as fast as possible?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, shortcut

I have a minor problem which i can't solve.
I have a layout with scrollview embedding a lot of views. 
Everything work fine with the android studio preview in design mode but when i want to access to a view at the bottom, i have to scroll the mouse wheel very long time in order to reach the bottom of the layout. So it works but as soon as i make a change of the view located at the bottom i have to scroll the mouse wheel very very long time so:

Is there a shortcut to go to the bottom of the layout or something else?

Even if i click on the view in the component tree window beside the preview, it selects the view but doesn't displays it.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015313/how-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scrollview-to-bottom/10217475

Comment: Thank you but i want to scroll into the design editor, not in the real device or the emulator.
anyway, i've found an alternative, i've commented almost all the views between the top and the bottom, so now, no need to scroll to much!